# Can't update the static bound property's value when text box's text changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I've got the following markup.

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="Address" 
         Text="{Binding 
                  Source={x:Static local:MainWindow.Boundie},
                  Path=SomeProp,
                  Mode=TwoWay}">
</TextBox>
```

In the code behind I have a static property like so.

```
Boundie = new Something { SomeProp = "old" };

static Something Boundie { get; set; }

public class Something { public String SomeProp { get; set; } }
```

I was expecting that if I type "new" into the data bound text box and breakpoint, the property's property would change. It's not the case. AM I using *Mode* the wrong way? Or do I need to do anything else, except setting it to *TwoWay*? Or is the approach inappropriate in this case all together?

Comment: Did you set the DataContext on your constructor? Did you make the new action AFTER or BEFORE InitializeComponent()?

Comment: If you are using a binding, your source has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface or has to expose a dependency property. Otherwise if you change your source the UI is not aware about that change.

Comment: As Il Vic said your class `Something` has to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Comment: @IlVic I'm only needing the update to go **from** the GUI **to** the data object. Do I still need to implement it? That'll require a bunch of new classes because I've reused the domain object model and I'm not in a position to start poking around in them right now...

Comment: @KonradViltersten when do you expect `SomeProp` property to be changed? By default it will happen on lost focus, but can be easily changed. Does it not happen on lost focus?

Comment: Do you use MVVM in your application? It will solve a lot of your problems.

Comment: @dkozl It should happen when the user types a key (but for now I'm happy if it happens on focus being lost). When I breakpoint on key up, the property of the static field isn't changed.

Comment: try adding `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` to your binding and see if it helps

Comment: @user2250152 You're probably right. The problem is that I need to show it to someone shortly and I can't (and shouldn't start rebuilding all too much because I want to avoid things going poof in the last seconds).

Comment: @dkozl I set it as you said. No luck yet. Do I need to play around with *NotifyOnTargetUpdated* and/or *NotifyOnSourceUpdated* too? I've tried those, of course, but still, no cookies...

Comment: @KonradViltersten no it should not be necessary. These properties will enable raising of `TargetUpdated` and `SourceUpdated` when value is pulled from object or send to object

Comment: @dkozl In such case, I've missed to do something else. Not sure how to troubleshoot, though. Perhaps I need to explicitly set **which** method to execute when a field changes? But I was under the impression that the whole joy of data binding is that I **don't need** to react on key up and update the object hold the information...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need to update **from** the GUI **to** the data object, implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` it is not mandatory.
As Sonhja suggested it is important to put the Boundie property initialization in the right point.
So you should insert `Boundie = new Something { SomeProp = "old" };` in a static contructor or just before the `InitializeComponent();` call (in the public constructor).

The reason is simple: if you `Boundie = new Something { SomeProp = "old" };` **after** the `InitializeComponent();` call, the binding has already tried to read the Boundie property value (which at that moment is null).

Comment: Dang, it's confusing... The change in the GUI is done by the user **eons** after the binding, so the way I figure, the order of init/binding doesn't matter. Hard to argue with the run-time environment and the harsh, unexpected reality on the screen, though...

Comment: Indeed the order is not important if you implement ´INotifyPropertyChanged' interface.
Anyway you can find more info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Your `.xaml` should look like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="Address" 
     Text="{Binding Path=Boundie.SomeProp, Mode=TwoWay}">
</TextBox>
```

Your `.cs` should look like this:

```
public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private Boundie _boundie;

    // You need Boundie to be public
    public Boundie 
    { 
        get; 
        set
        {
             _boundie = value;
             OnPropertyChanged("Boundie");
        } 
    }

    public Main()
    {
        Boundie = new Something { SomeProp = "old" };

        // Initialize component AFTER you initialized your attribute
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
    }

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

NOTE: Your Boundie attributes (SomeProp) MUST be public.

Comment: It says that *NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator* doesn't exist. Do I need to implement it myself?

Comment: It comes from System.ComponentModel